# Setting up Samba in Docker

Tags: docker, samba, server-message-block, smbclient

I am trying to set up a Samba server in Docker. I tried using dperson/samba image from docker hub at https://hub.docker.com/r/dperson/samba. I followed the instructions and tried to connect to it using smbclient to see if I could access the SMB terminal and download things from the shares. Although I can see a listing of the shares, I cannot open the SMB terminal. I get the message `SMB1 disabled -- no working group available`.

This is the command I'm using to start my Samba container:

```
-u "example1:badpass" \
-u "example2:badpass" \
-s "public;/share" \
-s "users;/srv;no;no;no;example1,example2" \
-s "example1 private share;/example1;no;no;no;example1" \
-s "example2 private share;/example2;no;no;no;example2"
```

This is the command I'm using to try to access the container:

```
smbclient -I <IP address of docker container> -L <ID of container> -U example1%badpass -m SMB3
```